# md-datepicker showing "Invalid Date" on load

Tags: datepicker, placeholder, invalidation, servicenow, angularjs-material

I am developing a Material form and have a md-datepicker input field that is showing Invalid Date on load instead of its placeholder:

[image]

When clicking on the drop down, the calendar starts all the way back in July 1934, which is less than ideal to say the least:

[image]

My code is pretty straight forward:

```
<div ng-switch-when="glide_date">
   <md-input-container>
      <label style="font-size: 130%; white-space: normal;" for="{{element.section_element_name}}">{{element.section_element_label}}</label> 
      <md-datepicker id = {{element.section_element_name}} ng-model="element.answer" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
   </md-input-container>
</div>
```

If I highlight and delete "Invalid Date", then my placeholder shows up correctly and the calendar drop down resets to the correct month.

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: your id value doesn't have quotes around it, that could be messing it up

Comment: Hey @ChristopherBales, thanks for the quick catch. Unfortunately, that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @Dave what is the initial value of `element.answer`? Please see `md-datepicker` [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker#attributes) about `ng-model`: _The component's model. Expects either a JavaScript Date object or a value that can be parsed into one (e.g. a ISO 8601 string)._

Comment: hi @VincenzoC, I've applied the code found here (https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6253), which fixed the Invalid Date issue, but now I'm running into another issue probably caused by Daylight Savings Time.  When I select a date such as 11/30/2017, it's actually recording one day before - 11/29/2017.  Any thoughts?